# fetch value from another javascript

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to pass the value(username) when scipt2 is getting called. script1 independently but after script1, so by the time script1 has the value populated but need it to be persistent to be available for future script calls.

script1.js

```
 var user = "";
function method1(){

    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var app = new UserText();
    app.setValue(username);
    // more logic
    }
function UserText(){

    this.getValue = function(){
        return this.user;
    };

    this.setValue = function(val){
        this.user = val;
    };
}
```

Script2.js

```
alert(UserText.getValue());
```

Comment: do the scripts have a shared context (e.g. a web application)?

Comment: yes they are part of the same application, but are called independently..its a FF plugin(xul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to expose something to the global scope. Right now, when you call `method1()`, the username is being stored in a specific instance of `UserText`. That specific instance is represented by your variable `app` which is currently scoped only to the `method1()` function.

One way to solve this is to simply move the declaration of `app` to the global scope. In other words, change the first part of the script to the following:

```
var user = "";
var app;
function method1() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    app = new UserText();
    app.setValue(username);
    // more logic
}
```

Note that I have moved the `var app` declaration to the global scope. Now you can access the instance with your user value through

```
alert(app.getValue());
```

On a related note, you should know that your `var user = "";` line does nothing at the moment, at least with the code that you have presented to us. When you are reading and writing to `this.user` inside your `UserText` class, it uses the instance of that class to store the information which is why you'll find your value inside the `app.user` property rather than just the `user` variable.

Comment: The script2, when executed didnot return value rather went to exception(catch) block...The solution didnot work...note that script2.js is trigerred after script1(modal xul) and independently by another xul(parent). Is there a way to save global values? even tried Application.storage.set(keyname, data); from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

Comment: You didn't mention that these were separate XULs in your question! Also, you did not say what the exception was, but I'm going to guess that it was a reference error for app being undefined. If the modal XUL was opened by the parent XUL, then you should be able to use the `window.opener` property to access the global scope of the first XUL. So you could try changing "script2" to have `alert(opener.app.getValue());` assuming "script1" has still has `app` declared in its global space as I did in my answer.

Comment: sorry for not being clear...parent XUL triggers script2.js, after modal-xul(used for authtication and capturing username) is done with script1.js. So issue is when script2.js triggers, how does it get the value set in app

Comment: @user1579906 Did you try using `opener` as I described in the previous comment?

Comment: yes, error is "errorReferenceError: app is not defined" without opener while errorReferenceError: opener.app is not defined in case of opener...

Comment: Was able to solve the issue by using modal return value...Tks for the help anyways